# Laravel 5.3 access hasone in elequant from view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to access a relations table from a collection of data passed in from the controller. I am able to iterate the collection in my view but I am unable to access the relationship data.

There are 2 tables:

- stocks (default model)
- stock_datas (has a foreign key stock_id which is already setup)

**Controller:**

```
public function getstock() {
        return view('vehicles.getstock', ['stock' => \App\Stock::all()]);
    }
```

**Model (App\Stock) and then (App\StockData)**

```
// From stock model:
public function stockdata() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\StockData');
    }

// Stock Data model:
public function stock() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Stock');
    }
```

**View (loop):**

```
@foreach ($stock as $k => $v)
     {{ print_r($v->stockdata()->get())->year }}
@endforeach
```

When I try the query below, I get a

```
 Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$year (View: F:\websites\tempsite\resources\views\vehicles\getstock.blade.php)
```

However, year is a column in the stock_datas table.

I am also able to print_r data from the \App\StockData() table so the reference to the table is correct as doing print_r(\App\StockData::all()) from the controller does return all the rows as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's [one to one relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), you should do it like this:

```
@foreach ($stock as $v)
    {{ $v->stockdata->year }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you :) I assume I am doing something wrong as all of the answers point to the same thing but I am getting a "Trying to get property of non-object when doing a {{ print_r($v->stockdata->year) }}"

Comment: Does every stock always has it's related stock data? If yes, can you post result of `dd($v->stockdata);` if you put this as first line inside `foreach`. If not, you should just do the check every time, like `is_null($v->stockdata) ? : $v->stockdata->year`.

Answer (score 1):

First one You have to change `{{ print_r($v->stockdata()->get())->year }}` this line, remove print_r. Next one in foreach loop you can do something like this

```
@foreach($stock as $one)
     {{ $one->stockadata()->first()->year }}
@endforeach
```

For better solution you should check if isset `$one->stockadata()->first()` 
and after that call ->year. Finally  code should be like this

```
@foreach($stock as $one)
 {{ isset($one->stockadata()->first()) : $one->stockadata()->first()->year : 'Default' }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `get()` method on any relationship You will always receive collection, no matter what relationship You have.

There are at least two (2) ways to solve Your problem:
1. `$v->stockdata->year`
2. `$v->stockdata()->first()->year`

I would suggest You to use first one, because Your `stockdata` has 1:1 relationship.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you :) I tried your options but get the following error on both: Trying to get property of non-object when doing a {{ print_r($v->stockdata->year) }} or {{ print_r($v->stockdata()->first()->year) }}

Comment: @mauzilla Just noticed, You have wrong relationship keys in `$this->hasOne('App\StockDatas', 'id', 'stock_id');` it should be `$this->hasOne('App\StockDatas', 'stock_id',  'id');`, because first key is foreign key and second is local.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

Stock.php model

```
class Stock extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';

        function stockdata() {
       return $this->hasOne('App\StockDatas', 'id', 'stock_id');
    }

    public function getStock(){
         return Stock::with('stockdata')->get();
    }
}
```

In contriller

```
 public function getstock(Stock $stock) {
    return view('vehicles.getstock', ['stock' => $stock->getStock]);
}
```

view

```
@foreach ($stock as $k => $v)
     {{ $v->stockdata->year }}
@endforeach
```